# Javascript / jQuery - Using variable outside get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a variable outside of my jquery .get request, but it keeps saying 'undefined'.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var userlat;
$.get("/ajax/getInitCoords", {}, function(data) {
    userlat = data.lat;
});
console.log(userlat);
```

If I move the console log part inside the brackets it works fine, but I need to access it outside that.

Comment: It doesn't work that way, that's why there is a callback function.

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many questions.